# Flutter Emulator crashes when playing a video with chewie/video player

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hello so I've been trying to get videos to play from my api to my flutter app but it keep crashing when the video screen comes up , the whole application and the emulator both crash when the video screen comes up.
here are some of the errors that i get :

```
W/Gralloc4( 4415): allocator 3.x is not supported
D/CCodec  ( 4415): allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
D/CCodec  ( 4415): allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
I/Codec2Client( 4415): Available Codec2 services: "software"
Lost connection to device.
```

I mostly followed the documentation and I can't seem to figure out what's causing the problem.
Here i'm gonna attach the flutter code :

```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final SlideItem movie;
  DetailScreen({ Key key, this.movie}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  DetailScreenState createState() => DetailScreenState();
}
class DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {

  VideoPlayerController controller;
  ChewieController chewieController;

  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        "https://mobileticketing.herokuapp.com/"+super.widget.movie.trailer);
    controller.initialize();
    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: controller,
      aspectRatio: 16/9,
      autoInitialize: true,
      looping: true

    );






  }

  @override
  void dispose()
  {
    controller.dispose();
    chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(super.widget.movie.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Chewie(controller: chewieController),

          ],
        ),



      ),

    );

  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I used this package. But I solved mine using a new package better_player which is based on chewie.

Here is the link https://pub.dev/packages/better_player

Comment: As soon as I add better_player as a dependency in my project, it no longer built in the emulator. I followed the install steps for better_player, and setting the sdk and kotlin versions didn't work for me when I wanted to enable multidex. So I ignored the sdk and kotlin version settings, and just did a 'flutter run --multidex' command, and it all seems to run now. Thanks for the better_player suggestion!